# GeoJSON markers in Google Maps Android SDK

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am writing my first Android app, and have come across a problem I cannot solve. I believe it is because I am not declaring variables properly, or at all. But cannot work out how to do it.

I am using Android Studio, creating a 'Google Maps Activity' as my project type, using the following code.

It imports a large local GeoJSON file that contains around 3000 points, and correctly displays the markers on the map, but....every marker has the same "minename" and "minedesc". It's as if they all get assigned the name (minename) and mine description (minedesc) of one particular feature/point in the GeoJSON file, which strangely, is not the first or the last feature in the file, it's around halfway through.

My GeoJSON is valid, I have checked on various validators, and am using the same file elsewhere with Google Maps Javascript API. So I am sure the GeoJSON is not the problem.

I understand that a variable declared with 'val' cannot be reassigned, but a variable declared with 'var' can. But it doesn't seem to be the case for me.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.goldmapsvictoria

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonLayer


class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Sets the map type to be "hybrid"
        mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

        // datalayer1
        val datalayer1 = GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.vms, this)
        val pointStyle = datalayer1.defaultPointStyle



        for (feature in datalayer1.features) {
            var mineName = feature.getProperty("Name")
            pointStyle.title = mineName
            var mineDesc = feature.getProperty("description")
            pointStyle.snippet = mineDesc

            val icon = defaultMarker(HUE_VIOLET)
            pointStyle.icon = icon
        }

        datalayer1.addLayerToMap()

    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your geojson file?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, as they are protected by intellectual property rights. I should also mention I have since rewritten this in Java, and didn't face the same issue. It is not appropriate to post that source code as the answer.